# When is $A \setminus S$ a prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

One of the definitions of a prime ideal $P$ of a commutative ring $A$ is

> $P \subset A$ is prime if $A \setminus P$ is a multiplicative set.

My question is: what conditions do I have to impose on a set $\emptyset \neq S \subset A$ so that $A \setminus S$ was a prime ideal?

By definition above $A \setminus(A \setminus S) = S$ must be a multiplicative set. Of course $S \neq A$. What are other conditions?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb Z\setminus 1$ is not so good since it is not multiplicatively closed to begin with.

Comment: @rschwieb aa.. yes, $1$ must be in it. But it does not change the question

Answer (score 4):

Another necessary condition is that $S$ is *saturated* meaning that if $ab\in S$, both $a,b\in S$. Of course $0$ cannot be in $S$ either if you want the complement to be an ideal.

Unfortunately, saturated multiplicative sets still don't characterize complements of prime ideals: it turns out that they are exactly the complements of *unions* of prime ideals. So another ingredient is needed (and I'm not sure if there is a concise one.)

One obvious sufficient condition to add, of course, is to ask for $R\setminus S$ to be an additive subgroup of $R$. Then the multiplicative ideal requirements work out automatically and you have a prime ideal. In fact this translates to a fairly natural condition on $S$: $a+b\in S\implies a\in S$ or $b\in S$. The fact that $S$ is saturated already implies that $R\setminus S$ already contains additive inverses for its elements.

Actually, reviewing everything here again, it looks like we've found a complete set of conditions. $R\setminus S$ is a prime ideal of $R$ iff $S$ is a saturated, multiplicatively closed, "additively prime" set not containing $0$.

Comment: "If $a + b \in S$ then $a \in S$ or $b \in S$"?

Comment: @arkeet I knew that would get additive closure but I was worried about inverses. But that is already taken care of by the saturation condition isn't it!